# Proper Syntax for playHaptic with watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

Objective-C Question

Hey, I need help figuring out how to use playHaptic with watchkit since the documentation is a little confusing. I have

```
        - (void)playHaptic:(WKHapticType)WKHapticTypeFailure
```

and I keep getting the error

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'playHaptic'
```

here is the documentation page: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/playHaptic:)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks, Chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play a haptic, you need to do something like this:

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic: WKHapticTypeNotification];
```

You can find the different types of haptics [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/WKHapticType).